# Why does Type.Name reverse the order of array brackets?

Tags: c#, arrays, types, variable-declaration

The value of `typeof(int[,,][][,]).Name` results in `"Int32[,][][,,]"`.

Why are the brackets in the name of the Type in the reverse order as compared to the declaration?